# How to write a "filter" stream wrapper for XML?

Tags: c#, xml, filter, stream, wrapper

I have some large XML feed files with illegal characters in them (0x1 etc).  The files are third-party, I cannot change the process for writing them.

I would like to process these files using an `XmlReader`, but it blows up on these illegal characters.

I could read the files, filter out the bad characters, save them, then process them... but this is a lot of I/O, and it seems like it should be unnecessary.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
using(var origStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
using(var cleanStream = new CleansedXmlStream(origStream))
using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(cleanStream))
using(var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(streamReader))
{
    //do stuff with reader
}
```

I tried inheriting from `Stream`, but when I got to implementing the `Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)` I lost some confidence.  After all, I was planning on removing characters, so it seemed the count would be off, and I'd have to translate each byte to a `char` which seemed expensive (especially on large files) and I was unclear how this would work with a Unicode encoding, but the answers to my questions were not intuitively obvious.

When googling for "c# stream wrapper" or "c# filter stream" I am not getting satisfactory results.  It's possible I'm using the wrong words or describing the wrong concept, so I'm hoping the SO community can square me away.

Using the example above, what would `CleansedXmlStream` look like?

Here's what my first attempt looked like:

```
public class CleansedXmlStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream _baseStream;

    public CleansedXmlStream(Stream stream)
    {
        this._baseStream = stream;
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        if (this._baseStream != null)
        {
            this._baseStream.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return this._baseStream.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return this._baseStream.CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return this._baseStream.CanWrite; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return this._baseStream.Length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return this._baseStream.Position; }
        set { this._baseStream.Position = value; }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        this._baseStream.Flush();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        //what does this look like?

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return this._baseStream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        this._baseStream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: 0x01 is SOH.  Stream classes default to ASCII encoding.  I would set your stream class to UTF8.  Try something like this :  StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: @jdweng per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx), `new StreamReader(Stream)` defaults to UTF8 so this would make no difference.

Comment: Perhaps you need to work at a higher level of abstraction. The `Stream` is binary data, whereas your invalid characters are a result of decoding that binary data.  Maybe you need a decorating `TextReader` rather than a decorating `Stream`?

Comment: @CharlesMager perhaps so.  I will investigate this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @CharlesMager's comment, I ended up not making a `Stream`, but rather a `StreamReader` like so:

```
public class CleanTextReader : StreamReader
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public CleanTextReader(Stream stream, ILog logger) : base(stream)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public CleanTextReader(Stream stream) : this(stream, LogManager.GetLogger<CleanTextReader>())
    {
        //nothing to do here.
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Reads a specified maximum of characters from the current stream into a buffer, beginning at the specified index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    ///     The number of characters that have been read, or 0 if at the end of the stream and no data was read. The number
    ///     will be less than or equal to the <paramref name="count" /> parameter, depending on whether the data is available
    ///     within the stream.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="buffer">
    ///     When this method returns, contains the specified character array with the values between
    ///     <paramref name="index" /> and (<paramref name="index + count - 1" />) replaced by the characters read from the
    ///     current source.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="index">The index of <paramref name="buffer" /> at which to begin writing. </param>
    /// <param name="count">The maximum number of characters to read. </param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">
    ///     The buffer length minus <paramref name="index" /> is less than
    ///     <paramref name="count" />.
    /// </exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="buffer" /> is null. </exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
    ///     <paramref name="index" /> or <paramref name="count" /> is
    ///     negative.
    /// </exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.IO.IOException">An I/O error occurs, such as the stream is closed. </exception>
    public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            var rVal = base.Read(buffer, index, count);
            var filteredBuffer = buffer.Select(x => XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(x) ? x : ' ').ToArray();
            Buffer.BlockCopy(filteredBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, count);
            return rVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.Error("Read(char[], int, int)", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Reads a maximum of <paramref name="count" /> characters from the current stream, and writes the data to
    ///     <paramref name="buffer" />, beginning at <paramref name="index" />.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    ///     The position of the underlying stream is advanced by the number of characters that were read into
    ///     <paramref name="buffer" />.The number of characters that have been read. The number will be less than or equal to
    ///     <paramref name="count" />, depending on whether all input characters have been read.
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="buffer">
    ///     When this method returns, this parameter contains the specified character array with the values
    ///     between <paramref name="index" /> and (<paramref name="index" /> + <paramref name="count" /> -1) replaced by the
    ///     characters read from the current source.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="index">The position in <paramref name="buffer" /> at which to begin writing.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The maximum number of characters to read. </param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="buffer" /> is null. </exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentException">
    ///     The buffer length minus <paramref name="index" /> is less than
    ///     <paramref name="count" />.
    /// </exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
    ///     <paramref name="index" /> or <paramref name="count" /> is
    ///     negative.
    /// </exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ObjectDisposedException">The <see cref="T:System.IO.TextReader" /> is closed. </exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.IO.IOException">An I/O error occurs. </exception>
    public override int ReadBlock(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            var rVal = base.ReadBlock(buffer, index, count);
            var filteredBuffer = buffer.Select(x => XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(x) ? x : ' ').ToArray();
            Buffer.BlockCopy(filteredBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, count);
            return rVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.Error("ReadBlock(char[], in, int)", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Reads the stream from the current position to the end of the stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    ///     The rest of the stream as a string, from the current position to the end. If the current position is at the end of
    ///     the stream, returns an empty string ("").
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.OutOfMemoryException">
    ///     There is insufficient memory to allocate a buffer for the returned
    ///     string.
    /// </exception>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.IO.IOException">An I/O error occurs. </exception>
    public override string ReadToEnd()
    {
        var chars = new char[4096];
        int len;
        var sb = new StringBuilder(4096);
        while ((len = Read(chars, 0, chars.Length)) != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(chars, 0, len);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

My unit test looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CleanTextReaderCleans()
{
    //arrange
    var originalString = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
    var badChars = new string(new[] {(char) 0x1});
    var concatenated = string.Concat(badChars, originalString);

    //act
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(concatenated)))
    {
        using (var reader = new CleanTextReader(stream))
        {
            var newString = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            //assert
            Assert.IsTrue(originalString.Equals(newString));
        }
    }
}
```

... and usage looks like this:

```
using(var origStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
using(var streamReader = new CleanTextReader(origStream))
using(var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(streamReader))
{
    //do stuff with reader
}
```

If anyone has suggestions for improvements, I'd be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried @JeremyHolovacs stream implementation but it still was not sufficient for my use case:

```cs
using (var fstream = File.OpenRead(dlpath))
{
    using (var zstream = new GZipStream(fstream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        using (var xstream = new CleanTextReader(zstream))
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
            prods = ser.Deserialize(XmlReader.Create(xstream, new XmlReaderSettings() { CheckCharacters = false })) as MyType;
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow not all relevant overloads must have been implemented.
I adapted the class as follows and it works as expected:

```cs
public class CleanTextReader : StreamReader
{
    public CleanTextReader(Stream stream) : base(stream)
    {
    }

    public override int Read()
    {
        var val = base.Read();
        return XmlConvert.IsXmlChar((char)val) ? val : (char)' ';
    }

    public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        var ret = base.Read(buffer, index, count);

        for (int i=0; i<ret; i++)
        {
            int idx = index + i;
            if (!XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(buffer[idx]))
                buffer[idx] = ' ';
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public override int ReadBlock(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        var ret = base.ReadBlock(buffer, index, count);

        for (int i = 0; i < ret; i++)
        {
            int idx = index + i;
            if (!XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(buffer[idx]))
                buffer[idx] = ' ';
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```